# how to change text in a button without change other tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to change text in a button without change other tags ?

my button :

```
<button id="ItemForSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
All Items
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

my dropdown-menu :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a id="AllItems" href="#">AllItems</a></li>
<li><a id="Countries" href="#">Countries</a></li>
<li><a id="Ships" href="#">Ships</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried the following But the span tag has been removed:

```
 $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function () {
 var item = $(this).text();
$('button[id=ItemForSearch]').text(item);
});
```

I need to just change the text.But I have no idea!!

Comment: $('#ItemForSearch').text(item) , you can use id to modify the text of button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace only the first text node in the button, that is the problem here. When you use `.text()` or `.html()` it replaces the entire contents of the button.

Try

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function () {
    $('#ItemForSearch').contents().eq(0).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N6N9U/)

Comment: thank a lot @Arun P Johny.You've helped me a few times. You are the best.